# Adding a UITextField freezes app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a UITextField to a view controller in my app using the following code :

```
passTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, CGRectGetMaxY(userTextField.frame)+20, self.view.frame.size.width-60, 30)];
passTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
passTextField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
passTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
passTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
passTextField.leftView = paddingView;
passTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
passTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
passTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
passTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passTextField.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:passTextField];
```

The whole app works fine but as soon as it tries to load the view that contains the 'passTextField' mentioned above, the whole app freezes forcing me but to kill it.

What am I doing wrong? I know it's something silly.

Comment: you probably cause an infinite loop somewhere. it is hard to tell where, the actual snippet does not indicate to where its location could be.

Comment: Try pause application and look what main thread doing.

Comment: add some more code. Where you added that code ?

Comment: if i comment out the line that adds the passTextField to that view, then the app runs just fine

Comment: surely there is an infinite loop somewhere as the memory and CPU readings spike up as soon as I try to load that view.

Comment: The code that you posted is solid. Your next steps should be creating breakpoints where you think the code has stopped and see where it is getting hung up at.

Comment: What about dispatching it in the main queue?

Comment: @DantePuglisi how would that help?

Comment: adding breakpoints shows it is trying to add the passTextField again and again

Comment: Then you are calling that function/method multiple/infinite times

Comment: Pretty sure I am not. There are other textfields being added to the view too in the same function as this one is in. Only the passTextField seems to be causing the problems. As I said, as soon as I comment out the line which adds the textField to the scrollview the app works fine

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I was using the paddingView I had defined for another UITextField in this same view which was causing it to go into an infinite loop. Declaring a seperate paddingView solved my problem.